# How to show value value based on previous selected answer

Tags: qualtrics

I'm new in qualtrics. I have a case how to show choices based on previous question answer.

Example :

Q1. How much price for a cup of coffee considered **cheap**?

1. 1$
2. 2$
3. 3$
4. 4$
5. 5$

Q2. How much price for a cup of coffee considered **very cheap**?

1. 1$
2. 2$
3. 3$
4. 4$
5. 5$

Q3. How much price for a cup of coffee considered **expensive**?

1. 1$
2. 2$
3. 3$
4. 4$
5. 5$

So, if Q1 I choosed **2nd** response, then Q2 only can show R1 (Q2 choices need to show only < Q1 choices), and Q3 only can show R3-R5 (Q3 choices need to only > Q1 choices). If Q1 choosed **1st** response, then Q2 only can show R1 (If Q1 choosed the lowest value then Q2 too only show the lowest value)

How can we do that? Sorry for my poor English

Thanks

Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display logic to the choices in Q2 and Q3.  For example, the display logic for the choices on Q2 would be:

1$ - always shown, so no display logic

2$ - If Q1 3$ is selected OR Q1 4$ is selected OR Q1 5$ is selected

3$ - If Q1 4$ is selected OR Q1 $5 is selected

4$ - If Q1 5$ is selected

5$ - might as well delete this choice since it should never be shown